# Testing primer for misspriming in 770 Mb lepidopteran genome

Tags: molecular-genetics, pcr, lepidoptera, primer

I designed **primer pairs for a lepidopteran genome** (Cydia pomonella, codling moth, ~770 Mb, ~60% transposable elements, [Reference Genome Paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-019-12175-9)). I have around **60 primer pairs** that bind to a specific chromosome and now i would like to **test for their specificity**, meaning i would like to test whether or not the primers are mispriming somewhere else in the genome. I tried it using *Geneious prime*, but to test all primers for all chromosomes takes a lot of time. Then i tried the *Primer-blast tool from NCBI*, but unfortunately Cydia pomonella is not listed as an available target genome.

Do you have any experience on how to test the primer specificity on (large) genomes in a reasonable time? Another thought would be to blast each primer and see if it is aligning an known transposable element (if yes: discard the primer) and then ultimately try to optimize the PCR itself. Is there another way to test beforehand?

Comment: I added and then deleted an answer that says primer3. Unfortunately that does not appear to be true. I would suggest looking around for a blast-based toolkit that accepts bulk input for this purpose. I was not quickly able to find one but did find this [helpful page](https://sequenceserver.com/blog/check-primer-specificity-with-blast/) with information about blast command line parameters that might be useful.

Comment: do you know biostars.org ?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, i will have a look in both :)